# What is the correct term "back-end", "back end" or "backend"?

Tags: word-usage, hyphens, compounds

I have a question.

What's the correct term?

**Back-end**, **Back end** or **Backend**

- I'm a software back-end developer
- I'm a software back end developer
- I'm a software backend developer

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be corrected or admonished for using any of these three. Google understands you perfectly [no](https://www.google.es/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=f7GLWPD9Dezw8Ae01YHgBw#q=back-end) [matter](https://www.google.es/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=f7GLWPD9Dezw8Ae01YHgBw#q=backend) [how](https://www.google.es/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=f7GLWPD9Dezw8Ae01YHgBw#q=back%20end) you type it. Wikipedia features [all three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_end) as well.

Personally, I'd write it as 'backend' or 'back end' as I'm not a fan of over-hyphenating (excuse my hypocrisy) unnecessarily.

(NGram removed)

<s>The NGram essentially supports the argument that you'll find all three in a lot of places,</s> and when I was Googling to test my own theories, a number of large tech sites appeared in each variation of spelling I searched for, leading me back to my first point:

Any of these is acceptable. Choose one you like and get coding.

**EDIT:** The NGram was misleading. Thanks for pointing that out in the comments.

Comment: The Ngram is misleading, as *back end* can refer to the literal back end of a town, or a house, or other things where you would not use *backend*. Pairing it with *developer* or *software* or some such would be a closer approximation.

Comment: I hate ngram. It is only useful in limited cases. Right.

Comment: I don't "hate" ngrams, but I don't like this one. I don't see how a spike in _back end_ around 1900 pertains to software developers.

Comment: That's the problem. They are useless for style issues. Editors decide style; not algorithms.

Comment: @Lambie - “Useless?” I wouldn’t go that far, especially if you look beyond the pretty graph and click on the links to see the actual usages. You can find a lot of reliable, contextual examples by doing that.

Comment: @J. R. But it doesn't answer the question, does it? For me, only a human being can answer a style question. Not a machine. The machine can offer up samples but cannot argue why one or the other might be best.

Comment: lulz @ "wikipedia uses..."

Comment: [Google Trends _strongly_ seems to favor "backend"](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?cat=32&date=all&q=%22back%20end%22,%22back-end%22,%22backend%22) so even though I agree any option will work that one might be most common? Then again I will admit I'm not sure if the results are thrown off because the algorithm behind it favors single words in general over terms made of multiple words.

Answer (score 26):

You can

1. Spell it as [**back end**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/back_end) when used as a noun, as for example "I am working on the back end of a project", and
2. Spell it as [back-end](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/back-end_2) when used as an adjective, as for example "The back-end technologies for this project will be Apache, MySQL and PHP."

Hyphenating compound adjectives is common in English, and both the links above use the hyphenated form for adjectival use.

Having said that, I agree that many software developers won't know the difference or care: if it doesn't show as a spelling error when typed into a computer, there is no problem. And if "backend" fails this test many will assume it's not in the computer's dictionary by accident.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out possible differences for using a word as noun or adjective!

Comment: For clarity, if you were to say `non` in front of `back end` would it be best to use `backend` instead so it is understood that it is not `non-back` `end`, but rather `non-backend`?

Answer (score 13):

From the [Microsoft Style Guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/style-guide/a-z-word-list-term-collections/b/back-end):

> ## back end, back-end
>
> Don't use if you can substitute a more specific term, such as server,
>   operating system, database, or network.
>
> Two words as a noun. Hyphenate as an adjective.

Comment: Finally someone with a clear opinion!